# Project build target lists is empty

Tags: android, andengine

List of targets in exlipse disappeared (( 
You can see the result in the image

[image]

And undefined error:

[image]

ANd 3:

[image]

[See here](http://sopost.ru/r/Dvp3KLe8)

Comment: Does your SDK location configured properly ?

Comment: Yes this is configured properly. Path is correct.

Comment: I was having a same error few days ago ended up Downloading a new Bundle,I have invested a lots of time investing about this and couldn't find the answer...:(

Comment: yes that is the only choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences -> Android and reset the sdk location

UPDATE:

It seems you have only updated the Android SDK version without updating the ADT. This can cause problems. Update the ADT to fix the problem. Go to Eclipse Help -> Check for Updates to update the ADT (Assuming you didn't install the ADT manually/offline)

Comment: SDK as if he had not been updated (( Please, see second image.

Comment: I am checked for updates. See Image #3. Alert "No updates were found".

Comment: Did you download the ADT and installed it manually or did you use the eclipse help -> install new software ? If you installed manually, the eclipse help -> check for update won't work. In that case you'll have to manually download the updated ADT and install.

Comment: So, I had to reinstall ADT?

Answer (score 1):

select **Window->Preferences**

A dialog window will appear, select **`Android`** and set the **SDK-Location** path.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by updating the Eclipse ADT plugin from Help->Install new software.